# Azure Pipelines multi-repo how to get Git Commit ID

Tags: git, bitbucket, azure-pipelines, delphi-xe

For an Azure Pipeline with multi-repositories, how can you get the GIT commit id from a checked out resource repository? Is it supported?

I'm using an Azure repo to store the pipeline yaml file, and checking out the build source on an agent to build there. We're using Delphi so we have to use an agent.

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyBitBucketRepo
    type: bitbucket
    endpoint: MyBitBucketServiceConnection
    name: MyBitBucketOrgOrUser/MyBitBucketRepo

trigger:
- pilot

pool:
  name: MyAgent
  demands: RADSTUDIO

variables:
  GIT_COMMIT: $(Build.SourceVersion) # <- How can I get the checked out Commit ID for the MyBitBucketRepo?
  GIT_BRANCH: $(Build.SourceBranchName) # And the branch name?

steps:
- checkout: MyBitBucketRepo

- script: dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
- script: echo $(GIT_COMMIT)
- script: echo $(GIT_BRANCH)
# todo set environment vars on agent with the Commit and Branch names required by msbuild script on agent
# todo run msbuild script on agent
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops under 'Repository details' suggests you can get info from variables, but the only one the 'documented' in the sample is .ref, wonder if the hash is in there too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how can you get the GIT commit id from a checked out resource repository? Is it supported?

I am afraid this is not supported by the Azure devops at this moment.

So, we could not use the predefined variables like `$(Build.SourceVersion)` to get the Git Commit ID from the multi-repositories directly.

To resolve this issue, we could use git command line to get the Commit ID and branch name:

```
 git rev-parse HEAD
 git branch -r
```

You could check my test YAML file for some details:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: TestProject
    type: github
    name: xxxx/TestProject
    endpoint: GitHub connection 1
  - repository: leotest
    type: bitbucket
    name: Lsgqazwsx/leotest
    endpoint: Lsgqazwsx

variables:
  GIT_COMMIT: $(Build.SourceVersion)
  GIT_BRANCH: $(Build.SourceBranchName)


stages:
- stage:
  jobs:
   - job: A
     pool:
       name: MyPrivateAgent
     steps:
     - checkout: TestProject
     - script: echo $(GIT_COMMIT)

- stage:
  jobs:
   - job: B
     pool:
      name: MyPrivateAgent
     steps:
     - checkout: leotest
     - script: git rev-parse HEAD
     - script: git branch -r
```

The result for `job B`:

[image]

Commit Id from bitbucket.org：

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it answers the question of whether it is supported or not. Git branch -r lists the branches, git branch --show-current should give the branch name but the head is detached. Also setting the agent machine environment variables via the pipeline does not appear to work. Agent is setup with a user that has permissions to set machine environment variables, works in powershell windows on the agent machine. The msbuild file is not picking up the machine environment variables that were just set (even though it was a separate script step) so have to debug that. Wish Delphi was supported.

Answer (score 2):

You can access commit from repository resources. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#variables-2) are all the supported variables and [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=example#variables-2) for resources.repositories.

In particular you are looking for `resources.repositories.<Alias>.version` property to get the commit ID, and `resources.repositories.<Alias>.ref` for branch name.

Here how to retrieve them in your case:

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyBitBucketRepo
    type: bitbucket
    endpoint: MyBitBucketServiceConnection
    name: MyBitBucketOrgOrUser/MyBitBucketRepo

variables:
  GIT_COMMIT: $[ resources.repositories.MyBitBucketRepo.version ]
  GIT_BRANCH: $[ resources.repositories.MyBitBucketRepo.ref ]

steps:
- script: echo $(GIT_COMMIT)
- script: echo $(GIT_BRANCH)
```

Answer (score -1):

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#pipeline-resource-variables%20suggests%20use%20can%20use%20the%20variable:%20resources.pipeline.MyBitBucketRepo.sourceCommit) suggests you can use the variable: `resources.pipeline.MyBitBucketRepo.sourceCommit`.

Comment: That's for pipeline resource definitions, not repository resources, and the sourceCommit you'll get will be for repo where the pipeline you're referencing is defined. It's poorly documented.