# How to get info from Azure Web App Service Deployment Center

Tags: azure, azure-devops

How to get commit ID from Azure Web App Deployment Center via PowerShell/Az Cli?

I'm interesting in Source Version:

[image: Example]

Comment: If you want to get  it in a powershell script ,You can access it via the environment variable   
               ***Get-Item Env:\BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE***

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT hey, could you provide a full script? I need to access to azure resource (Azure Web App Service).

Comment: Please refer SO threads [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38199473/how-to-retrieve-git-commit-id-and-message-in-vsts-tfs-build) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62156628/azure-pipelines-multi-repo-how-to-get-git-commit-id) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Answer - only via rest api. thx